# From find function to nested loops

Tags: matlab

> The file lake_powell.dat contains data on the water level in the reservoir for the 8 years from 2000 to 2007. These data are shown in Table 8.9. Use the data in the file to answer the following questions:
>   (a) Determine the average elevation of the water level for each year and for the 8-year period over which the data were collected.
>   (b) Determine how many months each year exceed the overall average for the 8-year period.
>   (c) Create a report that lists the month (number) and the year for each of the months that exceed the overall average. For example, June is month 6.
>   (d) Determine the average elevation of the water for each month for the 8-year period.

Originally, I had this question when I was learning about the find function. To that, I got the answer:

```
load LAKE_POWELL.DAT

% part a
table=[LAKE_POWELL]; % Puts LAKE_POWELL.DAT into a table
yearly=mean(table) % Finds the average elevation of the water level for each year
eight_years=mean(table(:)) % Puts the values of the matrix into one column vector before finding the average the entire matrix
    % part b
l=[eight_years] % Puts averages into matrix
i=mean(table) % Finds overall average of data
[y]=(find(table>i)) % Finds which months are above overall average

% part c
fprintf('Month # %f in year %f exceeds overall average',y,column) % Creates a report that lists the month and the year for each of the months that exceed the overall average


% part d
months=table'; % Transposes the table so that the months are now columns
per_month=mean(months) % Determines the average elevation of the water for each month
```

But now I am being told that I need to solve the same problems BUT with nested loops. So far I have:

```
    load LAKE_POWELL.DAT

table=[LAKE_POWELL];


for k=1:length(table)
    a=mean(table(k))
    eight_year=mean(a)

    b=zeros(1,length(table))
    for k=1:length(table)
        b(k)=find(table>eight_year)
    end
end
```

But of course, it's not working. Do you have any tips?

Comment: You can't use the same index variable in two nested for loops. Try changing the second ‘for k‘ to use ‘j‘ instead.

Comment: @such I keep getting an error: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements
in B and I must be the same.

Comment: How to do debug such an error.in Matlab: Enable stop on errors. Run the script until it fails. You'll then see on which row it fails, along with a back trace. Then evaluate the value of the left-hand side argument and the value of the right-hand side argument.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your data, you have a matrix with 12 rows (one for each month) and a 8 columns (one for each year).
First of all you need to learn to read values from and assign values to matrices.
The for loop `for k = 1:length(table) ... end` runs all the code between the `for k = 1:length(table)` and the `end` once for each integer value from `1` to `length(table)` (here you should notice that `length(table)` gives you the length of the largest dimension of `table` (here `12` - which I am guessing is not what you want)). Instead of `length(table)`, you can use `size(table,1)` for the number of rows and `size(table,2)` for the number of columns.

So in each iteration of the `for` loop `k` is a number. If you just put a number into a matrix, it will give you just one entry of the matrix more precisely `k`th entry in the column vector consisting of the columns of the matrix put on top of each other in order e.g. in your 12x8-matrix entry 15 will be the entry in the third row and second column of the table - that is `table(15)` is the same as `table(3,2)` (when the table have these dimensions).

To get a whole row or a whole column, you either need to index with a vector or use the `:`-operator. This is easily done: `table(i,:)` gives you the `i`th row of the table, and `table(:,j)` gives you the `j`th column of the table. What you are doing with the line `a=mean(table(k))` is setting `a` to the mean of the `k`th entry of `table` (that is the mean of a single number - so `a = table(k)`). What you probably ment to do was set the `k`th entry of `a` to the mean of the `k`th column of `table`: `a(k) = mean(table(:,k));`. The next line is then correct, except that you calculate the means of the results so far for each step, instead of just calculating the mean once, after the other calculations are done.

And now we arrive at problem b. First of all as explained in the comment by such, you should never use the same variable as the loop variable in a nested loop! Matlab will allow it, but you will most likely get the wrong result from your calculations!

The reason you get an error is `b(k)` is a reference to a single entry in a vector, while `find(table>eight_year)` may give you anywhere from `0` to `95` elements. There are many different ways of solving this problem! I suggest you play around with your code try to run only small segments at a time (can be done by selecting the lines you want to run and then pressing F9). Try to get to know what a `logical` matrix is (look at the result of `table>eight_year`, try to define some extra variables to help you. And use the documentations for the different functions that you use (select the function name and press F1), hopefully this will help you solve the problem yourself.

And you should be aware, that there are more errors in you code than I have mentioned. Some mistakes are easier to find e.g. when you do something not allowed in Matlab, it will tell you so and in which line it went wrong. But most of your mistakes are actually where you calculates something other than what you want. So try to sit down and really get to understand each step of your code, then it will be MUCH easier for you in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to type this up for me. It really helped me understand what I was doing wrong and what I need to do to answer this problem. Thank you!